# Extending a struct which is inside another struct

Tags: swift, swift3, extension-methods, swift-extensions

I'm trying to extend a `struct` that is already inside a `struct`. When I write the following code, I get

> declaration is only valid at file scope.

```
struct A {
    struct AA {

    }
}

extension A {
    extension AA {

    }
}
```

Is it invalid to write an extension inside an extension?

Comment: [The relevant portion of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID378): *"Extension declarations can’t contain deinitializer or protocol declarations, stored properties, property observers, **or other extension declarations.***"

Comment: @Hamish Correct, but not at all relevant.

Comment: @Raphael Given the only explicit question OP asked was "*Is it invalid to write an extension inside an extension?*" – I'd say it's pretty relevant.

Comment: @Hamish Right, the titular "question" and the one in the body have different answers. I missed that last line since it was pretty clear from the rest of the body what they wanted (which is not to discuss language specification but extend `AA`), my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do that is:

```
extension A.AA
{
   func test()
   {
      print("Test")
   }
}
```

It just worked in my playground